# Put a return in catch {} block in a foreach loop

Tags: c#

I have a code block (see below). So, if I get an exception in work 1, where will the code execution continue, and the same with work 2. Will it continue with work B or start a new turn in the `foreach`-loop? What's the difference between a `catch {}` with and without a `return` in it?

```
foreach (var item in arr)
{
    //// Work A
    try
    {
       // work 1
    }
    catch { }                                
    try
    {
        // work 2
    }
    catch { return; }                                
    //// work B                                                    
}
```

Comment: A try block can have more than one catch block.  Set each catch block to act on a different exception.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Ignore the exception
catch { }

//Continue with the next iteration
catch { continue; }

//Exit the loop
catch { break; }

//Exit the method
catch { return; }
```

So to answer your question;

An exception in `work 1` will essentially ignore the exception and proceed to run `work 2`.

An exception in `work 2` will exit the method entirely.

Answer (score 6):

If you get an exception in work 1, it will do whatever's in the `catch` block, and then continue on to work 2 (unless you throw an exception or do something else to bail out in work 1's catch block).

The `return` in the catch block will exit the entire method containing that `foreach` loop. If you want to just exit the `foreach` loop, use `break;`. If you want to continue on to the next item, use `continue;`.

Additional reference on `foreach` loops here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ttw7t8t6.aspx

Answer (score 1):

1. If exception in Work1, it will continue to Work2
2. If exception in Work2, it will be caught and return the outer function of the foreach.
3. return means return from this function.